# Unable to query from firebase using orderByChild and equalTo

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

json data from export:

```
[ null, {
  "branch" : 6725,
  "id" : 1234,
  "lat" : 17.1234,
  "lng" : 78.345,
  "name" : "test",
  "time" : "2018-12-11 18:12:40"
}, {
  "branch" : 6724,
  "id" : 12345,
  "lat" : 17.234,
  "lng" : 78.23457,
  "name" : "suchit",
  "time" : "2018-12-12 09:34:22"
} ]
```

don't know what null is doing there.

Unable to query from the above structure using equalTo:
current Code:

```
var branch=6725;
var cars_Ref = firebase.database().ref().child('liveusers');  
var cars =cars_Ref.orderByChild("branch").equalTo(branch);
                 cars.on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
                         var obj = snapshot.val();
                         console.log(obj.name + " is available.");
                 });
```

Note: Any Other approach is also appreciated.

Comment: What are u getting in the log?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: What does "unable to" mean? Does the `child_added` callback not fire? Did you check the JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: no errors in console.expected output is the index 1 data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the JSON from export.

Comment: Which name did you get in the log?

Comment: @PeterHaddad no data. child_added callback is not firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var branch = 6725;
var  ref   = firebase.database().ref("liveusers");

ref.orderByChild("branch").equalTo(branch).on("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val().;
        console.log(childData.name);
     });
 });
```

Here you put the reference at `liveusers` and then loop inside the snapshot and retrieve the name that should satisfy the query.

Comment: How is this functionally different from the code in the question?

Comment: @Suchitkumar can you do console.log for `ref` and `childSnapshot` and tell me what you get

Comment: @Suchitkumar if you remove the orderbychild().equalTo() do you get any data in the log?

Comment: yes after removing both the clause i'm getting both the entries.

Comment: Okay @Suchitkumar try `orderByChild("branch").equalTo(6724)`

Comment: Hi, I got the issue. It Was related to the key passed.Thanks

Comment: can we index more than 1 key in firebase?